# Where is stdlib.h / stdint.h in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, std, include-path, stdint

I was googling a bit and heard that although `stdint.h` was not shipped with old versions of Visual Studio, it should be there in Visual Studio 2010.

However, I have this project that's supposed to use it, but it says it can't find either `stdlib.h` or `stdint.h`.

[image]

Why is that and how could I fix this?

---

Running Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0 on an x86 Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stdint.h` is in the standard VC include directory for VS 2010:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
```

I assume by `stlib.h` you mean `stdlib.h`, which is also there.

Also, why is `#import` being used for `stdint.h` instead of `#include`?  I'm not sure that `#import` would work, since `stdint.h` is a straight-up header, not a type library (though it looks like you're in debug mode, so the build worked?).

Comment: I fixed the corresponding typo, thanks. The directory you specify seems to be [included already](http://grab.by/9NXh).

Comment: I was given this file by my supervisor and must admit that I'm no C/C++ expert at all :) Changing `#import` to `#include` worked fine, thanks!